# How to assign payload to dto properties in NestJS

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I want to validate DTOs using Zod in NestJS but unfortunately, existing packages failed to satisfy my need. I've come up with the following code from somebody, which I understand but I need help removing the nested `.data` field from the DTO. Following is my code

Validation Pipe (bound globally)

```js
import { Injectable, ArgumentMetadata, BadRequestException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ZodDtoClass } from '../utils/zod-dto.interface';

@Injectable()
export class ZodValidationPipe {
  transform(value: Record<string, unknown>, metadata: ArgumentMetadata) {
    const schemaClass: typeof ZodDtoClass = metadata.metatype! as unknown as typeof ZodDtoClass;

    if (!schemaClass.schema) return;

    const result = schemaClass.schema.safeParse(value);
    if (!result.success) {
      throw new BadRequestException(result.error.flatten());
    }

    return { data: result.data };
  }
}
```

DTO creator class

```js
import { z } from 'zod';

export abstract class ZodDtoClass<T extends z.ZodSchema> {
  static schema: z.ZodSchema;

  data: z.infer<T>;
}
```

The DTO

```js
import { z } from 'zod';
import { ZodDtoClass } from '../../utils/zod-dto.interface';

const schema = z.object({
  title: z.string().min(5).max(35).nullish(),
  body: z.string().max(140).nullish(),
  attachment: z.instanceof(File).nullish(),
});

export class CreateFeedDto extends ZodDtoClass<typeof schema> {
  static override schema = schema;
}
```

In the Controller

```js
export class FeedsController {
  constructor(private readonly feedsService: FeedsService) {
  }

  @Post('/create')
  create(@Body() createFeedDto: CreateFeedDto) {
    console.log({
      dto: createFeedDto.data.title,
      //                 ^^^^ wat to remove this field, so can access like: createFeedDto.title
    });

    return this.feedsService.create(createFeedDto);
  }
}
```

Want to get rid of that `data` field from DTO